# Packing or making executables in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am new to C++. Before, when working with Java, I could make an executable as either a jar or exe file. Is it is possible in C++ for any other format? I need an format that works on Linux. I am using Eclipse as development IDE - is there any built in way to export as an executable file?

Comment: Are you working on a Linux environment?

Comment: yes i am in ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Err, C++ always creates an executable file...

Comment: @mathepic I think we should take this question as asking how to create (i.e. compile) an executable file from a C++ file in Eclipse on Ubunut 10.04 - i.e. take the asker through the steps of setting the build options if needed, the output file name and then how to run the output file from the command line. (Also any chmod problems he may run into.)

Comment: @Stephen Okay then, I don't know anything about eclipse though... I'll retag the question.

Comment: @mathepic: that depends on your definition of executable file. a dynamic library does not need to implement the main() function and is not executable on its own.

Comment: @Daniel I was referring to the fact that there is not JAR or anything like that. Yeah, there are shared libraries, but since hes new to C++, I doubt he knows anything about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux uses [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format for executables. Just setup Eclipse CDT IDE and creator will ask you if you want executable, static or shared library. Although it can be directly set in Project Properties (C/C++ Settings -> Build -> Build Artifacts)

On Java you are running `class` files, which can be packed into `jar` archives, because `class` is an executable format recognized by Java Virtual Machine. Thus one needs JVM to run jar or class files. But JVM can be packed together with your jar/class files into single executable, native to the certain system. That's why you have an option to build executable in Java. C++ doesn't use virtual machine, so usually there's no need for another format than system native executable.

Also note that it may be a little bit tricky if you want Linux executable format and you are working on Windows.